# download csv file in java and dojo rest call

Tags: javascript, java, dojo

Please help me update this java code without using controller, where the java class directly calls rest api. Please share few java code and dojo.
Thanks

```
enter code here <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuBarItem">
    <span>List Options</span>
    <div id="fileActions">
    <!-- Form -->
        <form id="myform">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuItem">
            <span>Power Systems</span>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu" id="download1">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem"  onclick="submitForm('retiredsystemscsv')">Retired Power Systems</div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem"  onclick="submitForm('downloadcsv')">Orderable Power Systems</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" onclick="submitForm('downloadcsv')">Z Systems</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuItem">
            <span>Storage</span>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu" id="download2">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" onclick="submitForm('downloadcsv')">Internal Storage</div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" onclick="submitForm('downloadcsv')">External Storage</div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Script to submit the download -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sendForm(){
            var form = dojo.byId("myform");
            dojo.connect(form, "onsubmit", function(event){
                // Stop the submit event since we want to control form submission.
              var xhrArgs = {
              url : "http://localhost:8080/wle/rest/sizingoptions/retiredsystemscsv?sessionID" + document.getElementById('sessionID').value,
              handleAs : "json",
                headers : {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
                },
                postData : dojo.toJson(values),
                load : function(data) {
                form.submit();
                },
                error : function(error) {
                                    }
                                };
                            dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
                                        });
                                            }
                                    dojo.ready(sendForm);

                            </script>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @POST
    @Path("/retiredsystemscsv")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response downloadCSV(@QueryParam("sessionID") String sessionID, JSONArray csv) {
        String status = "success";
        if (sessionID != null) {
            try {
     int numberOfIntervals = SconResource.maxInterval(sessionID);
               boolean zPresent = SconResource.isZPresent(sessionID);
                PowerSystemFlavor psf=new PowerSystemFlavor();
                SystemConfig [] a =  psf.getRetiredSystemList("Retired Power System");
              //  webUser.setcsv(op);

Comment: please add your comment above in your question dont post it as a comment !!!